# Preserve http error code and body in response from outbound gateway to inbound gateway

Tags: spring-integration

Actually, below post provides a solution to my problem, and i since could not comment on it, i created a question here.

[Spring integration: preserve http error code and body in response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45627072/spring-integration-preserve-http-error-code-and-body-in-response?answertab=active#tab-top)

Can i have solution of this explained using Spring Xml based configuration or with annotations ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why Java DSL solution is not for you, but here is some XML variant on the matter:

```
<int-http:inbound-gateway path="/service" error-channel="httpErrorChannel"/>

<int:chain input-channel="httpErrorChannel">
    <int:transformer expression="payload.cause"/>
    <service-activator 
         expression="T (org.springframework.integration.support.MessageBuilder).withPayload(ppayload.responseBodyAsString)
                            .setHeader('http_statusCode', payload.statusCode)
                            .build()"/>
</int:chain>
```

Comment: Java DSL uses lambda, and for now not comfortable with lambdas. appreciate your help.